# How to generate a indeterminate number of WAR files using Maven?

Tags: maven, build, maven-2, build-process, maven-3

I would like to generate multiple WAR files, during the build cycle of my project. I already know how to add multiple *dest-file*, and other configuration with the maven-war-plugin. But I want to know if there is way to generate an **indeterminate number of war** during the build cycle, without writing configuration for each WAR.

I want to generate a build for each clients, I have the following directory structure in my project:

```
| pom.xml
+ src
  + main
    + clients
      + client1
      + client2
      + client3
      + ...
      + clientn
```

I would like to know how to generate a WAR for each client directory. I just want to create a Maven configuration, then just care about adding a new folder then `mvn package` and get *n* WAR packages.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Maven cannot do that by itself, so I ended up creating a script that invoke Maven for each folder found in `src/main/clients`.

### In Unix

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

###
# Check for Apache Maven home environment variable.
###
M2_HOME=`$M2_HOME`
if [ -z "$M2_HOME" ]; then
        echo "Error: M2_HOME variable not set. Please set Apache Maven home."
        exit
fi

###
# Build all client packages.
###
echo "Build start."
for f in $0/src/main/clients/*
        do echo Building: %f
        $M2_HOME/bin/mvn package -Dclient.id=`basename $f` -Dclient.path=$f -DskipTests
done;
echo "Build end."
```

### In Windows

```
@ECHO off
SET M2_HOME=%M2_HOME%
CD %~p0
ECHO Build start.
FOR /r /d %%G in (src\main\client\*) DO (
    ECHO Building: %%~nG
    %M2_HOME%\bin\mvn package -Dclient.id=%%~nG -Dclient.path=%%G -DskipTests
)
ECHO Build end.
```